# Export Query to CSV, formatting issue with array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, csv

I have a table with 4 fields I am querying. I am trying to out put the query to a csv pointer and I am having truble formatting the columns and rows.

I am getting back 1 line :

```
Status,Account,PO,Field,1000,2112,HTWC2112,Booyah,1000,877,HTWC4293,Booyah
```

I want:

```
Status,Account,PO,Field`
1000,2112,HTWC2112,Booyah
1000,877,HTWC4293,Booyah
1000,877,HTWC42870,Booyah
```

Here is what I have to far:

```
<?php 
require('db.php');
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv');

ob_end_clean();
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
$array = array('Status','Account', 'PO', 'Field');
fputcsv($output, $array, ',');

$rows = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT * FROM TestCSVImport');
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rows))
{
  fputcsv($output, $row,',');
}
mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: Where are you seeing this 1 blank line?  Browser, notepad?

Comment: Browsers don't render newlines, you need `nl2br()`. Notepad and some other applications require `\n\r` to show a newline.

Comment: So, As I opened notepad with excel i realized that it was almost formatted correctly. (I had only created CSV from excel prior and did not realize that they render different, thank you for that.   What i get is that the header data is columns 1-4 and actual  data is columns 2-5